# Difficulty in setting up query using 'CASE WHEN'

Tags: sql, if-statement, case

I have this query.

The logic of the select is whether the `@USER_NAME` parameter exists within the 3 following tables in their respective columns:

MODEL_RESPONSIBLE MR> MR.USER_NAME
    RESPONSIBLE_PLANT_MODEL> RPM.USER_NAME_MPR
    RESPONSIBLE_AREA_MODEL> RAM.USER_NAME_AM

```
DECLARE 
@USER_NAME varchar(max) = 'lorem',
@PROFILE_USER varchar(max) = null;

SELECT  @USER_NAME, UserProfile =
      CASE @USER_NAME
         WHEN IN(RAM.USER_NAME_AM) THEN @PROFILE_USER = 'PROFILE 01'
         WHEN IN(RPM.USER_NAME_MPR) THEN @PROFILE_USER = 'PROFILE 02'
         WHEN IN(MR.USER_NAME) THEN @PROFILE_USER = MR.PROFILE_NAME
         ELSE @PROFILE_USER = ''
      END,
   UserProfile
FROM MODELO M 
INNER JOIN MODEL_RESPONSIBLE MR ON MR.ID_MODEL = M.ID_MODEL
INNER JOIN RESPONSIBLE_PLANT_MODEL RPM ON RPM.ID_MODEL = M.ID_MODEL
INNER JOIN RESPONSIBLE_AREA_MODEL RAM ON RAM.ID_MODEL = M.ID_MODEL
```

The test did not work as it should.

How best to assemble the query, it would be with the CASE or IF?

How to assign the value correctly to @PROFILE_USER?

> ERROR: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IN'.

Comment: Tag the dbms used, some non-ANSI SQL there.

Comment: As a note, you can fix that particular error just by removing the `IN` after each `WHEN`.  You will then get another error -- but I'm not sure which one.  If I were to guess, it would be related to the `=` after each `THEN`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Exactly. Exception in ' = '

Comment: You should tag the question with the database you are using, which is presumably SQL Server.  You should also try to understand the queries in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

you need to refer to the field in every line of the statement

```
DECLARE 
@USER_NAME varchar(max) = 'lorem',
@PROFILE_USER varchar(max) = null;

SELECT  @USER_NAME,
      CASE 
         WHEN @USER_NAME IN(RAM.USER_NAME_AM) THEN @PROFILE_USER = 'PROFILE 01'
         WHEN @USER_NAME IN(RPM.USER_NAME_MPR) THEN @PROFILE_USER = 'PROFILE 02'
         WHEN @USER_NAME IN(MR.USER_NAME) THEN @PROFILE_USER = MR.PROFILE_NAME
         ELSE @PROFILE_USER
      END as UserProfile,
   UserProfile
FROM MODELO M 
INNER JOIN MODEL_RESPONSIBLE MR ON MR.ID_MODEL = M.ID_MODEL
INNER JOIN RESPONSIBLE_PLANT_MODEL RPM ON RPM.ID_MODEL = M.ID_MODEL
INNER JOIN RESPONSIBLE_AREA_MODEL RAM ON RAM.ID_MODEL = M.ID_MODEL
```

Comment: I just try like you suggested but it appears the same error.

Comment: I understand the answer, but it is both logically and syntactically incorrect.  The upvotes are particularly puzzling.

Comment: @ThamiresCunha I have made another change, I didn't realise in your original script you were setting a variable inside the case statement occasionally. If this doesn't work, I would suggest that you remove the case statement entirely and return all fields you are referring to and ensure that works before progressing further, it could be a collation error, an incorrect field name... check those first and then come back to the case statement. It would also help to see expected outcome and the data

Comment: @GordonLinoff the code is as close as possible to what OP posted, I did notice a small error in the else statement which I have now corrected

Comment: @ChrisJ I try again. Error:  Incorrect syntax near '='.

Comment: Error when assigning the value to @PROFILE_USER

Comment: @ChrisJ You can't assign a variable a value within a CASE statement. You need something like [@PROFILE_USER] = CASE when 1 then 'A' else 'B' END

Answer (score 0):

The `CASE` expression can be written as:

```
SELECT  @USER_NAME,
      @PROFILE_USER =
      CASE @USER_NAME
         WHEN RAM.USER_NAME_AM THEN 'PROFILE 01'
         WHEN RPM.USER_NAME_MPR THEN  'PROFILE 02'
         WHEN MR.USER_NAME THEN  MR.PROFILE_NAME
         ELSE ''
      END as UserProfile,
   UserProfile
FROM MODELO M
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is in a big mess, but I believe this is along the lines of what you wanted your `CASE` statement to be:

```
@PROFILE_USER =
CASE
     WHEN @USER_NAME IN (RAM.USER_NAME_AM) THEN 'PROFILE 01'
     WHEN @USER_NAME IN (RPM.USER_NAME_MPR) THEN 'PROFILE 02'
     WHEN @USER_NAME IN (MR.USER_NAME) THEN MR.PROFILE_NAME
     ELSE ''
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query simply isn't SQL.  It has problems both logical (the inner joins only succeed if records are in all three tables) as well as syntactic.

I believe this is what you want to do:

```
SELECT @USER_NAME,
       (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MODEL_RESPONSIBLE MR WHERE MR.ID_MODEL = M.ID_MODEL AND RAM.USER_NAME_AM = @USER_NAME)
             THEN 'PROFILE 01'
             WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM RESPONSIBLE_PLANT_MODEL RPM WHERE RPM.ID_MODEL = M.ID_MODEL AND RPM.USER_NAME_MPR = @USER_NAME)
             THEN 'PROFILE 02'
             ELSE (SELECT MR.PROFILE_NAME FROM RESPONSIBLE_AREA_MODEL RAM WHERE RAM.ID_MODEL = M.ID_MODEL AND MR.USER_NAME = @USER_NAME)
        END) as UserProfile
FROM MODELO M ;
```

If you want to set the variable @UserProfile, then it would look like this:

```
SELECT @UserProfile =
       (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MODEL_RESPONSIBLE MR WHERE MR.ID_MODEL = M.ID_MODEL AND RAM.USER_NAME_AM = @USER_NAME)
             THEN 'PROFILE 01'
             WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM RESPONSIBLE_PLANT_MODEL RPM WHERE RPM.ID_MODEL = M.ID_MODEL AND RPM.USER_NAME_MPR = @USER_NAME)
             THEN 'PROFILE 02'
             ELSE (SELECT MR.PROFILE_NAME FROM RESPONSIBLE_AREA_MODEL RAM WHERE RAM.ID_MODEL = M.ID_MODEL AND MR.USER_NAME = @USER_NAME)
        END)
FROM MODELO M ;
```

Or, alternatvely, `LEFT JOIN` might be appropriate:

```
SELECT @USER_NAME, 
       (CASE WHEN RAM.USER_NAME_AM IS NOT NULL THEN 'PROFILE 01'
             WHEN RPM.USER_NAME_MPR THEN 'PROFILE 02'
             ELSE MR.PROFILE_NAME
        END) as UserProfile
FROM MODELO M LEFT JOIN
     MODEL_RESPONSIBLE MR
     ON MR.ID_MODEL = M.ID_MODEL AND RAM.USER_NAME_AM = @USER_NAME LEFT JOIN
     RESPONSIBLE_PLANT_MODEL RPM
     ON RPM.ID_MODEL = M.ID_MODEL AND RPM.USER_NAME_MPR = @USER_NAME LEFT JOIN
     RESPONSIBLE_AREA_MODEL RAM
     ON RAM.ID_MODEL = M.ID_MODEL AND MR.USER_NAME = @USER_NAME;
```

This would be the more natural way of expressing this logic.

As a note, your syntax suggests SQL Server.  You cannot both set variables and return data using a single `SELECT` statement in SQL Server.